# Kendo Grid Shows HTML

Tags: jquery, html, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have a Kendo EditorFor control.When i type something there it's correctly saved in Database and then it shows in Kendo Grid like that.I need to remove that html codes from kendo grid.
[image: Kendo Grid Column]

### Kendo Grid

```
@(Html.Kendo().EditorFor(model => model.NewsData).Tools(tools => tools.Clear()
    .Formatting()
    .Bold()
    .Italic()
    .Underline()
    .JustifyCenter()
    .JustifyFull()
    .JustifyLeft()
    .JustifyRight()
    .InsertUnorderedList()
    .InsertOrderedList())
    .HtmlAttributes(new
        {
            @class = "form-control k-textbox tab-shift"
        }
```

))

How can i remove that Html's ?

Comment: If the database does have that `html` in its field, then I would find how to parse html with kendo grid.
If the database does *not* have that html in its field, then I would look to see if there is a template perhaps doing it. My guess is that the database has the html content also.

Comment: @xinthose in my grid also encoded false .BUT it's not working . columns.Bound(c => c.NewsData).Title("NewsData").Encoded(false));

Comment: Maybe its double encoded @TechGuy